# Inner paragraph fading out when scrolled down to edges of containg div

Tags: html, css

Given a rectangular `<div>` of fixed dimensions with overflow: hidden and which contains only paragraphs `<p>`, I am trying to add a "fade out" effect such that when the div is scrolled down, the part of the paragraph sliding under the fictitious orange regions (see pic below) are gradually faded out from bottom to top, and vice versa for the other region. The paragraphs need to remain selectable.

I am looking for a simple way (preferably css only, perhaps using multiple borders?) to accomplish this. Note that:

- inner box-shadow won't work since the paragraph will be on top of it
- :after and :before selectors won't work since they will scroll up and down with the paragraph
- I was hoping to use box-image with a linear gradient, but the containing div already has its won border (left, right, and bottom).

If there is a way to make it work in spite of the above issues, please let me know. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Write short and add your tried code to understand other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
div::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(61,68,97,0) 0%, rgba(61,68,97,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(61,68,97,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(61,68,97,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(61,68,97,0) 0%,rgba(61,68,97,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(61,68,97,0) 0%,rgba(61,68,97,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(61,68,97,0) 0%,rgba(61,68,97,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(61,68,97,0) 0%,rgba(61,68,97,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#003D4461', endColorstr='#3D4461',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

The 'before' pseudo element will be on top (higher z-index) of the `<div>` and will have the same proportions (width and height), so you just have to adapt the background gradient to your needs.

The only problem on this approach is the `<p>` text is not selectable, because the before element is covering it...

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - unfortunately the ::before element still slides up with the content (i.e. doesn't stick to the edges of the containing div when scrolling down); also I would need to have the inner elements selectable as well, will edit the qstn.

Answer (score 0):

This plnkr does exactly what you need, but it runs a very light javascript code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jKNy3lLSvuZh8cqivnzz?p=preview

I user a wrapper with absolute positioned divs with gradients on its backgrounds. The javascript only calculates the size of the scrollbar for the shadow divs not to be covering it.

the html code:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="top-shadow"></div>
  <div class="bottom-shadow"></div>
</div>
```

the css code:

```
.content-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top-shadow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0);
}

.bottom-shadow {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=0);
}
```

and finally the javascript code (it depends on jquery):

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  function scrollbarWidth(selector) { 
    var containerEl = $(selector)[0];
    return containerEl.offsetWidth - containerEl.clientWidth;
  }

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.top-shadow').css('right', scrollbarWidth('.content')+'px');
    $('.top-shadow').show();
    $('.bottom-shadow').css('right', scrollbarWidth('.content')+'px');
    $('.bottom-shadow').show();
  });

})();
```